# How to insert picture into your Word document?

Tags: 2010, web-part

I have a Document Library with column type Hyperlink or Picture (Signature).

**How to insert (Signature) into your Word document?**

I find this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb497430.aspx) for insert Picture into word.

I problem is : How do insert the internet picture(url)  in word ?

I use this code

```
  ImagePart imagePart = mainPart.AddImagePart(ImagePartType.Jpeg);
  //Send an HTTP request and get the image at the URL as an HTTP response
  HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fileName);
   WebResponse myResp = myReq.GetResponse();

  //Get a stream from the webresponse
  Stream stream = myResp.GetResponseStream();

  imagePart.FeedData(stream);
```

but i get error

The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Comment: had you try to specify a internet URL? the problem can be the machine's security settings

Comment: I do not know how use insert images from the internet into a Word!

Comment: did you try to use something like this:
WebClient Client = new WebClient ();
Client.DownloadFile("http://i.stackoverflow.com/Content/Img/stackoverflow-logo-250.png", @"C:\folder\stackoverflowlogo.png");

Than add the image from your local path?

Comment: I don't save image in local path.

Comment: can you save it in local path or not?

Comment: No , I can not.

Comment: The error says clearly that the server you are requesting from is not allowed to access that. Did you try it with a image free available like the logo url mentioned from Salvatore?

Comment: I use a picture in Library.

Comment: you can do the same thing with a picture library too

Comment: if i use every picture , i get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add Credentials for HttpWebRequest .

```
myReq.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
myReq.PreAuthenticate = true;
myReq.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

It is work for me :)